# Compatibility Settings for 64 bit applications are grayed out

Tags: windows, 64-bit, compatibility, windows-7-x64

I am trying to choose the setting "Disable Visual Themes" from the [Compatibility tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8L2F.png) for a specific 64 bit .exe application but the Compatibility options are grayed out.

I tried several ways but Officially you cant change compatibility options for 64 bits applications.

Is there any way to do it?

Thank you,

J.

Comment: Works for me. What do you mean by "officially you cant change compatibility options for 64 bits applications"? Where's the reference for that statement? Because the statement is false.

Comment: Did you tried in a 64-bit .exe ? There are many questions about it in several forums but here: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/316-compatibility-mode.html you can read at OPTION ONE, third step : NOTE: If the Compatiblity options are grayed out, then it is a 64 bit program and cannot be changed.

Comment: Well, one of us is wrong. Either it's me, or whoever wrote that comment. It's absolutely trivial to work out which one of us is wrong.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I can confirm that this is indeed the case. You cannot change the compatibility settings for a 64bit executable the same way you can do for 32bit executables. Sorry, that I can't be any more help than just confirm what you already know. I would love to find a solution to this myself.

Answer (score 3):

Click Change settings for all users at the bottom of the compatibility tab and it will let you select compatibility options.

I ran into this because for some reason an application kept telling it it was not compatible with windows vista. I have no idea why it was doing that but it wouldn't let me install it, and I ran into the same greyed out compatibility options.

Clicking that button allowed me to remove the check box for "run in compatibility mode for" allowing me to install the program.

Comment: I tried this and it works for some .exe programs but not for others. How do I make it work for the program that has it greyed out for `change settings for all users`?